# symfony 2 Column cannot be null

Tags: symfony

I have an issue in symfony 2. When I try to insert a new row in a table (Sinedries) which has a foreign key i get the error Column 'kod_pelati' cannot be null. 
the master table "Pelates":

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sinedries", mappedBy="pelates")
 */
private $sinedries;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->sinedries = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

the detail table entity "Sinedries":

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="kodikos", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $kodikos;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="kod_pelati", type="integer")
 */
private $kodPelati;
```

.....

```
    /**
 * Set kodPelati
 *
 * @param integer $kodPelati
 * @return Sinedries
 */
public function setKodPelati($kodPelati)
{
    $this->kodPelati = $kodPelati;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get kodPelati
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getKodPelati()
{
    return $this->kodPelati;
}
```

....

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pelates", inversedBy="sinedries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kod_pelati", referencedColumnName="kodikos", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $pelates;
```

the controller:

```
        $sinedria = new Sinedries();
    $sinedria->setKodPelati($idPelati);             


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $form = $this->createForm(new SinedriesType(), $sinedria);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isValid()) {
    // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
        $em->persist($sinedria);
        $em->flush();
```

I tried without form but the occurs the same problem. Also a similar controller with update statement works fine.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding nullable=true to your join column

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because sql is expecting a value for this column,

You can solve this by either of these ways:

1. Set kodPelati as nullable:

   /**

   - @var integer
   - @ORM\Column(name="kod_pelati", type="integer", nullable = true)
     */ 
     private $kodPelati;
2. If you want the user to give this input a value as mandatory; Then you can give this field a validation consraint:

   /**

   - @var integer
   - @Assert\NotBlank()
   - @ORM\Column(name="kod_pelati", type="integer", nullable = true)
     */
     private $kodPelati;